# Finding a derivative through the definition

Tags: limits, inequality, derivatives

Let $f$ be a function of domain $\mathcal D$ and codomain $\mathcal C$, both subsets of $\mathbb R$, and $\mathcal D_{\mathrm{cl}}$ the set of cluster points of $\mathcal D$. I want to find $f'$ by "guessing" it via derivative properties and show that, indeed,
$$\begin{align}
\forall\varepsilon>0\quad \forall x&\in\mathcal D\quad
\forall c\in\mathcal D\cap\mathcal D_{\mathrm{cl}}\quad
\exists\delta(\varepsilon,c)>0\quad\\
&0<|x-c|<\delta\Longrightarrow
\left|\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}-f'(c)\right|<\varepsilon\quad.
\end{align}$$
How should I find an appropriate $\delta$?

As an example, consider
$$\begin{matrix}
f:\mathbb R^*\to \mathbb R\\
\qquad\;\;x\mapsto \sin\frac1x
\end{matrix}\quad\therefore\quad
\begin{align}
f':&\mathbb R^*\to \mathbb R\\
&x\mapsto -\frac1{x^2}\cos\frac1x
\end{align}\quad,$$
thus proving
$$\begin{align}
\forall\varepsilon>0\quad \forall x,c&\in\mathbb R^*\quad
\exists\delta(\varepsilon,c)>0\quad\\
&0<|x-c|<\delta\Longrightarrow
\left|\frac1{{x-c}}\left(\sin\frac1x-\sin\frac1c\right)+\frac1{c^2}\cos\frac1c\right|<\varepsilon\quad.
\end{align}$$